# C# MVC5 - StructureMap & log4net - BuildStack.Current.ConcreteType

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net, structuremap

I have ASP.NET MVC5 project in C#.
Use StructureMap & StructureMap.Net4 (v:3.1.1.0) and log4net (v:1.2.15.0) and StructureMap.Web (v:1.0.0.0).

In StructureMap - DefaultRegistry i need use a call class instance of LogManager like in my older project

```
x.For<ILog>().Singleton().Use(c => LogManager.GetLogger(c.ParentType ?? c.BuildStack.Current.ConcreteType));
```

but in this SM does not a **BuildStack**

```
For<ILog>().Use(c => LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType())).Singleton();
```

I got in log file only this class name

```
7 Project.DependencyResolution.DefaultRegistry INFO  10/10/2016 15:26:51 - Test
```

but I call it from HomeController like this

```
_log.Info("Test");
```

and I neet log with HomeController line like:

```
   7 Project.HomeController INFO  10/10/2016 15:26:51 - Test
```

Is there any solution (besides creating an instance log4net in each class where the call)? How use log4net with StructureMap and got correct class name in SM Use statment ?

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: does it work if you're skipping DI? `private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof({{currentClass}}));`

Comment: Yes, it´s work fine when I use `typeof(SomeClass)` (in SomeClass or Project.DependencyResolution.DefaultRegistry class) or `this.GetType()` (in DefaultRegistry), but I need got a calling class -> in this case Project.HomeController name in DefaultRegistry class DI with something like **c.BuildStack.Current.ConcreteType (StructureMap's IContext)** but it this version of SM missing maybe or is there any way how to do it.